# window.focus() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a chrome window(Parent window) of latest version. When I click a button on the parent window, a new second chrome window(child) should open and it should come in front. When i click the same button(in parent window) for the second time, already opened child window should come in front (Focus should set in the child window).

**Issue**:
First time when I click the button, I am using **"window.open(uri)"** to open a new chrome child window and it is focused in front.
Second time when I click the button, i am using same **"window.open(uri)"** to bring the already opened chrome window to *front* but this is not working. The operations to be performed on the child window is properly happening and data populated are correct but the window is not coming in front.

I have tried using window.focus(), window.blur() in the onclick() event of button, but they are hopeless.

Appreciate if I could get some answers.

Comment: save the child window in a variable and call `new_example_window.focus()`

Comment: You have tried `let w=window.open(uri)` and then `w.focus()` ? Also is the page in the window from the same origin as the script? If so, and you have control of the page, you can do `<script>window.focus()</script>` in the new window

Comment: Yes, I have tried like function onclick() { var win = window.open(uri); win.focus(); }  This is also not working. Both windows are from same origin. First time when the button is clicked, it is working properly

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, additionally you can add event listener to child window, to detect when user closes child window, then asign `null` to `childWindow` variable.

```html
<body>
    <button>
        Open window
    </button>

    <script>
        let childWindow = null;
        const button = document.querySelector("button");
        
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (childWindow) {
                childWindow.focus();
                return;
            }

            childWindow = window.open(
                "https://www.mozilla.org/",
                "mozillaWindow",
                "popup, width=400, height=400"
            );
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
 window.open(
            "http://google.co.za", null,
            "toolbar=yes,titlebar=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,fullscreen=yes,centerscreen=yes"
            );
```

When you click on the button it will open the window, if you again click on the button then it will bring the window on the front.

Comment: can anyone explain or provide feedback on why it got -1

Comment: Thanks Aditya. I have tried the above code, but it didn't worked. Do we have any chrome version related limitation for window.open()?

Comment: @Gopinath I don't know about it, I am using chrome Version 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)